# Защита от захвата экрана Camtasia и др. во время просмотра Flash-видео в браузере

Tags: защита

Какие технологии можно попробовать применить для реализации программы, которая могла бы противодействовать таким программам как Camtasia и ей подобных? Возможно ли во Flash попробовать реализовать алгоритм, который будет хотя бы искажать содержимое видео, при этом не мешая его смотреть пользователю в браузере?

Comment: Искренне надеюсь, что это невозможно.

Comment: Это принципиально невозможно

Answer (score 1):

Нет, всегда можно сграбить через Display Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Нет.

Из области усложнения могу предположить использование DirectX, поскольку программ захвата, умеющих работать с ним, значительно меньше, чем программ, просто записывающих экран.

Правда не в курсе, возможно ли использовать DirectX из флеша.

Comment: Придется разбираться с Flash, возможно там есть API для низкоуровневых действий... хотя после долгих "гуглений" в сети, не выявлено ничего подобного(.